# difference between health care services and typical goods and services

Tags: financial-economics

Why is the market for health care services is substantially different than the market for typical goods and services

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Please see our policy on homework questions. http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Economics.SE. This could be an interesting question, but you need to be more specific about what differences you are thinking about. For example, an answer to this question could be, "The market for health care services is substantially different than the market for typical goods and services because it is a market of health care services..." Asking a more specific question will lead to better answers (and may prevent your question from being closed).